# Trigger to prevent column value from A to B, and from B to A

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to create a trigger that prevents a column to be updated as follows:

If column **value is "A", it cannot be updated to "B"**,
and **if column value is "B", it cannot be updated to "A"**.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cancelled_order()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$BEGIN
    IF OLD.status = 'Cancelled' THEN NEW.status != 'Accomplished';
    END IF;
    IF OLD.status = 'Accomplished' THEN NEW.status != 'Cancelled';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$;

CREATE TRIGGER No_cancelled_acomplished
    BEFORE UPDATE OF status
    ON clinical.tb_orders
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE cancelled_order();
```

The error that comes out is:

> ```
> Sintaxis error: !=
> ```

Any idea, why?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! Please construct a fiddle on dbfiddle.uk and provide some sample data and your desired result - put any data from the fiddle here also (use the edit question link).

Comment: The crucial question is what to do in case of an illegal attempt: Just prevent changing the column value? Reset the column to a default value? Cancel the whole update silently? Raise an exception (to cancel the whole transaction)? Please be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you want to accomplish logically, shouldn't:

```
IF OLD.status = 'Cancelled' THEN NEW.status != 'Accomplished';
END IF;
IF OLD.status = 'Accomplished' THEN NEW.status != 'Cancelled';
END IF;
```

actually say something like this?

```
IF OLD.status = 'Cancelled' AND NEW.status = 'Accomplished' THEN RETURN OLD; -- Set A = A when trying to set it to B
END IF;
IF OLD.status = 'Accomplished' AND NEW.status = 'Cancelled' THEN RETURN OLD; -- Set B = B when trying to set it to A
END IF;
```

My syntax might be slightly off for PostgreSQL, but my point is isn't this the kind of logical expression you're looking for? (You shouldn't be doing a boolean comparison in the `THEN` clause, which I think is why it's mad about the `!=`.)